# User Profile Pictures not showing up after changing WFE

Tags: 2013, user-profile, my-site, user-profile-property

We just recently switched to a new Web Front End.  Everything is working fine with the exception of the User Profile Pictures.

We are not importing them from AD and they worked fine on the old WFE.  Users that had Profile pictures uploaded, now show up as a red 'X' like it is pointing to a bad link.  Trying to re-upload does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a key in the mysites web config

```
<add key="aspnet:AllowAnonymousImpersonation" value="true" />
```

Needs to be set to false.

I am not sure why it was set to true when the new front end was stood up.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your user profile service is alive and that all of your user profiles are present. Also, verify that your “PictureUrl” profile property is set correctly. Then, update your profile photo store with: 
`Update-SPProfilePhotoStore –CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 –MySiteHostLocation http://mysite`

For more details, see [this great resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-office-2010-and-profile-pictures.aspx).