# Is it possible to sniff all Sharepoint's outgoing traffic?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, exchange-server, exchange

I'm having lots of troubles configuring Sharepoint 2013 to fetch user profile pictures from Exchange 2013 and [I've already asked a question about the whole problem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160207/profile-pictures-not-showing-in-user-profiles-after-configuring-sharepoint-for-s).
Here I want to ask something more specific.

In the Sharepoint ULS I cannot find any traces that report a call to the Exchange Web Services, nor to the "GetPhoto" URL (see below), nor anything that I can relate to Exchange. I tried filtering by several keywords (exchange, photo, picture, pictureUrl, autodiscover, etc...) and I couldn't find anything.

Am I wrong about my presumption that such a call should be logged in ULS?

**Is there a way to sniff the Sharepoint's outgoing traffic and sort it out in order to find what happend between it and Exchange?** (this would probably help me a lot in troubleshooting)

I know that Exchange is reachable without problems from the Sharepoint machines, both through a browser and through PowerShell scripts that use Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll. In particular I checked that the following URL responds with the desired image file:

```
https://my.dns/EWS/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=test.sharepoint@test.com&size=HR648x648
```

There are no errors, no warnings whatsoever, everything is apparently configured fine except that the images won't show in the user profiles.

Comment: You're going to need to install a low-level network sniffer like Wireshark on the server. Fiddler is not going to help in this case. https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can capture traffic using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).
Take a look at [this](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2013-Workflow-Advanced-Workflow-Debugging-with-Fiddler) blog from Andrew Connell on how to get Fiddler to capture SharePoint requests.